# Linux: logwatch(8) is too noisy. How can I control the noise level?

Tags: linux, monitoring, syslog, logwatch

Our Linux systems run [logwatch(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logwatch) utility by default. On a RedHat/CentOS/SL system, Logwatch is called by the `/etc/cron.daily/` cronjob, which then sends a daily email with the results. These emails have a subject like:

```
Subject: Logwatch for $HOSTNAME
```

The problem is that by default these daily emails are too noisy and contain a lot of superfluous information (HTTP errors, daily disk usage, etc) which are already monitored by other services (Nagios, Cacti, central syslog, etc). For 100 systems, the email load is unbearable. People ignore the emails, which means that we may miss problems which are picked up by logwatch.

How can I reduce the amount of noise generated by logwatch, but still use logwatch to notify us of significant problems?

I'll post my own answer below, but I would like to see what others have done.

**Note**: I have a similar question regarding FreeBSD, at [FreeBSD: periodic(8) is too noisy. How can I control the noise level?](https://serverfault.com/questions/277652/freebsd-periodic8-is-too-noisy-how-can-i-control-the-noise-level)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Overall, the available documentation for Logwatch lacks adequate explanation and is often far too vague. I pieced together some useful examples, and have reduced the Logwatch noise by over 95%.

Here's what I have found.

Keep in mind that you can find some Logwatch documentation at `/usr/share/doc/logwatch-*/HOWTO-Customize-LogWatch`, and it contains a few useful examples.

1. On RHEL/CentOS/SL, the default logwatch configuration is under  `/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf`

   These settings can be overriden by placing your local configuration under `/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf`. Place the following in that file to tell logwatch to completely ignore services like 'httpd' and the daily disk usage checks:

   ```
   # Don't spam about the following Services
   Service = "-http"
   Service = "-zz-disk_space"
   ```
2. Sometimes I don't want to completely disable logwatch for a specific service, I just want to fine tune the results to make them less noisy. `/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/services/*.conf` contains the default configuration for the services. These parameters can be overridden by placing your local configuration under `/etc/logwatch/conf/services/$SERVICE.conf`. Unfortunately, logwatch's ability here is limited, and many of the logwatch executables are full of undocumented Perl. Your choice is to replace the executable with something else, or try to override some settings using `/etc/logwatch/conf/services`.

   For example, I have a security scanner which runs scans across the network. As the tests run, the security scanner generates many error messages in the application logs. I would like logwatch to ignore errors from my security scanners, but still notify me of attacks from other hosts. This is covered in more detail at [Logwatch: Ignore certain IPs for SSH & PAM checks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/278504/logwatch-ignore-certain-ips-for-ssh-pam-checks/280829#280829). To do this, I place the following under `/etc/logwatch/conf/services/sshd.conf`:

   ```
   # Ignore these hosts
   *Remove = 192.168.100.1
   *Remove = X.Y.123.123
   # Ignore these usernames
   *Remove = testuser
   # Ignore other noise. Note that we need to escape the ()
   *Remove = "pam_succeed_if\(sshd:auth\): error retrieving information about user netscan.*
   ```

   "
3. logwatch also allows you to strip out output from the logwatch emails by placing regular expressions in `/etc/logwatch/conf/ignore.conf`. HOWTO-Customize-LogWatch says:

   > ignore.conf:    This file specifies regular expressions that,
   >                   when matched by the output of logwatch, will
   >                   suppress the matching line, regardless of which
   >                   service is being executed.

   However, I haven't had much luck with this. My requirements need a conditional statement, which is something like 'If there are security warnings due to my security scanner, then don't print the output. But if there are security warnings  from my security scanner *and* from some bad guys, then print the useful parts-- The header which says "Failed logins from:", the IPs of the bad hosts, but not the IPs of scanners.'
4. Nip it at the source (As suggested by @user48838). These messages are being generated by some application, and then Logwatch is happily spewing the results to you. In these cases, you can modify the application to log less.

   This isn't always desirable, because sometimes you want the full logs to be sent somewhere (to a Central syslog server, central IDS server, Splunk, Nagios, etc.), but you don't want logwatch to email you about this from every server, every day.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, however if I recall correctly, there were some services (I believe something to do with email rejections) that were not being parsed correctly from the logs and were therefore being listed in some sort of "other" category and the entire lines from the logs were being sent by email. This was extremely noisy. I therefore just edited the logwatch source code and added/changed the respective filters and cut probably 20kb per email. This was a few years ago, so I'm sure logwatch has improved since then, but I haven't updated my version in case it hasn't.

Comment: You can address #4 by configuring rsyslog to *only* forward those logs to the central log server, without storing them in a local log file.

Comment: Instead of completely replacing the executable, as #2 suggests, you can sometimes also create a wrapper around the original. The logwatch data comes in via stdin. Your wrapper may simply contain something like grep -V "stuffidontwant" | /usr/share/logwatch/...<originalscript>"

Answer (score 6):

Yes - logwatch is often too noisy. You already mentioned disabling checks completely.

If you don`t want to do that you have to prevent certain events to appear.
For instance - it is not interesting if nagios connects via ssh to a DMZ system. But is is interesting if there are other logins via ssh.

We use rsyslog instead of ksyslogd (first install rsyslog, then remove ksyslogd).
With rsyslog you can fine-tune what goes to the logs and what not (e.g. build a expression that drops messages from sshd cointaining "nagios connected"). That way logwatch will report useful information only.

Another case might be xinetd - I don`t want to get informed about successful connects - this can be configured in xinetd itselv - without disabling the logwatch-check for xinetd.

Answer (score 4):

As a point of interest I followed option 2 form the answer by [Stefan Lasiewski](https://serverfault.com/users/36178/stefan-lasiewski) but for my purposes I wanted to only include specific lines rather than exclude all the noise I didn't want.

I was configuring vsftpd so I created `/etc/logwatch/conf/services/vsftpd.conf` and instead of using something like `*Remove = testuser` which removes rows which include the text `testuser` I used the line `*OnlyContains = "testuser"` which only returns rows including that text.

These 2 scripts work very basically by using `grep` and `grep -v`.

The difference being that you can use `*Remove` as many times as you want but with `*OnlyContains` you have to use it once if you want something or something else or something else. So for multiple values you do `*OnlyContains = "testuser|testuser2|testuser3"`

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered funneling the email status messages to a listserver, maybe one that can provide digests based on programmable attributes of size and/or duration/age? The approach does not reduce the amount of logging being emailed, but can control the amount of individual emails by batching to reduce the emailing frequency.

Comment: I have. We've also considered a syslog-only solution, where we filter out some of the noise. However, for simplicity we wanted to see if it was possible to control this stuff at the source.

Comment: If you are looking at "nipping" it at the source and minimizing any mishaps in doing so, then you might consider limiting the efforts to adjusting the logging levels when available.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to quiet down the output from the sshd service. Some of the sections were quite long and could not be controlled by setting the detail level.

It's not an ideal solution, but I wound up overriding the sshd *script* by copying it from here: `/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/sshd` to here: `/etc/logwatch/scripts/services/sshd`

Of course, you now have to keep up on any updates to that script file, but it does give you very fine control over what is output. Alternatively, I suppose you could pipe the output of `logwatch` through a tool like `awk` or `sed` to strip out what you don't want, but that seemed harder to me.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same question on [UNIX&Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513371/have-logwatch-send-reports-only-once-a-week/513409#513409) and here is the answer I that fixed it for me:**

You can tell logwatch to look at 7 days instead of 1 day by changing the Range parameter in your `logwatch.conf`:

```
Range = between -7 days and -1 days
```

You can tell `logwatch` to run weekly instead of daily by moving it from the weekly cron directory to the daily `cron` directory:

```
mv /etc/cron.daily/00logwatch /etc/cron.weekly/
```

Thanks to @JeffSchaller